# Specific Group By query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

initial table:

```
 1   1   3
 1   1   4
 1   2   1
 1   2   3
 2   1   5
 2   1   2
 2   2   2
 2   2   3
```

after group by on third column and sum on that column:

```
 1   1   7
 1   2   4
 2   1   7
 2   2   5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, SUM(Col3)
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

Something
 like that??

Answer (score 4):

Specify multiple columns to group by and it will only group when the values in all the columns are the same:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, Sum(ColC) as Summation
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ColA, ColB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select one , two, sum(three)  from (
  select 1 as one, 1 as two, 3 as three from dual
  union
  select 1 as one, 1 as two, 4 as three from dual
  union
  select 1 as one, 2 as two, 1 as three from dual
  union
  select 1 as one, 2 as two, 3 as three from dual
  union
  select 2 as one, 1 as two, 5 as three from dual
  union
  select 2 as one, 1 as two, 2 as three from dual
  union
  select 2 as one, 2 as two, 2 as three from dual
  union
  select 2 as one, 2 as two, 3 as three from dual
) group by one, two;
```

Comment: so was my answer wrong and you didn't understand the root? Or group by works different in MS SQL?

Comment: no..its work fine in ms sql. don't know who voted downwards for this answer.